# How to create a custom stack in sliver appear in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

Hi Everyone I am creating a profile page for a flutter app.

The SliverAppBar needs to show the below view when in the expanded state:

[image: Header with profile image in a RED circle]

And below view when the user scrolls the silver list.

[image: scrolled header with profile picture overflowing the header]

As you see this is a custom stack that I can create.

I don't know how to do it in slivers in a flutter.

Any links would also be highly appreciated to learn in-depth about flutter and slivers especially.

Code for the collapsed stack:

```
             Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
                        width: 2000,
                        height: 80,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(blurRadius: 5.0, color: Colors.black87)
                        ])),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, top: 5),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(blurRadius: 5.0, color: Colors.black87)
                          ],
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.cyan, width: 3.0)),
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                            "assets/images/food/avocado-f.jpg"),

                        radius: 50,
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `SliverPersistentHeader` and create your own `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate`.

In the build method you add your Stack view and you can use Transform or SizedBox to scale and transform the circle depending on the height of the header.

There is a nice tutorial that explains how to use this widget
https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-code-a-dynamic-header-in-flutter-e171ec2231bf